# AnkhSVN - keep local copy and get latest version

Tags: version-control, ankhsvn

I m new to use ankhSVN and having issues. I have created some new files which are not commited. It was required that i need to get latest version. I right clicked the folder and selected update. I didnt get the latest version and also my files were not present. It had a question mark icon towards the left.
Ideally i want to know what is the procedure to use ankhSVN.

Thanks and regards,
Ashish Agarwal
Ashish.Agarwal@Renishaw.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unrelated: Please remove your e-mail address from your question if you don't want to receive spam.. you can be notified on updates via RSS and mail via your profile settings].

The 'folders' you see in Visual Studio are not normal folders/directories. They are just filters on your project. For some project types they map to actual folders (E.g. C#, VB and websites), but for other projects they don't (E.g. C, C++, Setup, Database, ...).

So actually you are just updating the selection of the filter/folder and everything below.

For most tasks you should always update on either the solution, the project level or a single file, as updating a subdirectory without the project referencing the files inside is an operation that can leave you with a broken project. (New files won't be included in your project and old files won't be removed).

AnkhSVN allows you to update the whole directory at once by checking the [X] Recursive checkbox at the bottom of the dialog, but this is currently not the default setting.